# 180 volts ac from 240 volts primary

Tags: power-supply

i am trying to make an elevator brake test tool, my input voltage is standard out our home power outlets at 240 vac, i need to convert this to 180vdc as an output required by the test equipment,  im trying not to use a step down transformer, as i was told the trf would be too big, my testbox is 200x150x80mm. How can i reduce 240 vac to 180 vac wthout a trf???

Comment: This isn't a helpdesk.

Comment: Determine the current required and the tolerance of the voltage then buy or design an AC to DC converter or power supply. To get help here, you need to have a specific question not a vague general requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I would think 15 x 12 V batteries rated for the current you need, should do the job.

Not as heavy as elevator ballast weights at least.

The charger must balance power into the batteries.